# Desapareció mi Base de Datos Mysql al actualizar Python

Tags: mysql

Estaba trabajando con una Base de datos en Heidi y con Python 3.8 en Visual Studio. Ayer actualicé a 3.9, comencé a instalar el pip, pyqt5, pandas. Y ahora me doy cuenta que la BD ha desaparecido. Alguien sabe qué pudo haber pasado o como la puedo recuperar.
Al inicio estaba usando el Workbench pero un dia comenzó a cerrarse al abrir cualquier BD, por eso me cambié a Heidi.

Comment: el workbench es el cliente, igual que Heidi. No sabemos qué comandos corrieste en la actualización o cómo está instalada la base de datos. Que el cliente no vea una BD no significa que no esté disponible. ¿Qué pasa si creas la conexión de nuevo?

Comment: @Alfabravo Hola. He creado una nueva sesión y nada. Las tablas con extensión frm y lbd están en una carpeta Workbench, siempre estuvieron ahí. Las únicas que ahora se muestran son las que estan en la carpeta de Mariadb. Las puedo importar?

Comment: ah... o sea instalaste otro motor de base de datos y no ves las bases viejas? estas confundiendo ide con motor?